# Documents deleted using Google Docs API still visible in Google Drive

Tags: google-docs-api, google-drive-api

I've built an integration using the Google Docs API (using GData) allowing users to create/edit documents from another application.  Originally, when documents were deleted we would have them permanently deleted. They were no longer visible in Google Docs or Google Drive.  Now when they are deleted using the Google Docs API, they are still present in the list of Documents in Google Drive.  When you attempt to follow the link to the document you arrive at the "Sorry, the page (or document) you have requested does not exist." page.

Does Google Drive not honor the actions taken via the Google Docs API?  Do I need to delete these documents using both the Google Docs API and the Google Drive API? What if the user has not migrated to Google Drive?  Is there a way to tell if the have migrated?  Or do I force them to migrate so I can use the Google Drive API to keep their Google Drive clean of these dead documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Drive API and the Docs List API both operate on the same resources so you only have to use one of them (and we recommend the former).

With the Drive API you can [trash](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/trash) or [delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/delete) files. When you trash a file, it will still be listed in Google Drive with a label to mark it as in trash, so that you can still [untrash](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/untrash) it.

If you want to remove a file completely, you have to use the `delete` method.

Comment: The problem that we are seeing is that the Drive API and the Docs List API are not operating the same on the same resource.  A Delete issued through the Docs List API is removing the resource completely.  However, through the Drive Web UI we still see the resource listed.  Clicking the listed resource we encounter an error indicating that the resource is no longer there. If the expectation is that both APIs should work the same on the underlying resource, this must be a bug in Google Drive.

Comment: A delete from the Documents List API by default trashes the document. If you want to permanently delete a document with the Documents List API you have to add the `?delete=true` parameter: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#deleting_documents_and_files

Comment: We are appending ?delete=true to our call.  `docsService.delete(new URL(GoogleDocsConstants.URL_BASE_FEED
                                       + "/"
                                       + documentListEntry.getResourceId().substring(documentListEntry.getResourceId().lastIndexOf(':') + 1)
                                       + "?delete=true"), documentListEntry.getEtag());`

Comment: Basicly the resource, as listed in the Drive UI, is dead.  Attempting to delete it we receive a message saying it can't be deleted

Comment: It would be great if you could capture the HTTP request and response so that we can troubleshoot the issue. If that is hard from your code, you might want to try the OAuth 2.0 Playground: https://code.google.com/oauthplayground/

Comment: As I was collecting this HTTP request and response it started working correctly again and I feel like the boy who cried wolf...however....I still have ten test files/resources listed from about 1:30pm MDT to 3:00pm MDT stuck in my Google Drive that don't relate to any exist content and can't be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem while using Google Drive APIs.  I think when the Delete api deletes the document, their is still some linking with parent folder remains, so the browser renders the document.  when I tired to delete the document with below piece of code, it properly works for me.

DriveService.Childern.Delete(parentResId, fileId).Fetch(); // fileId=>ResourceId of document to be deleted

Comment: In the v3 API, the syntax has changed slightly: drive.files().delete(id).execute();

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I believe this is some kind of caching on the drive UI.

The file does appear to be deleted correctly and is not visible to the drive API.

The orphaned stubs eventually get deleted as the cache is cleared every so often.

I found that by removing the file from the parent and then deleting it meant that it was easier to see what was going on when using the drive UI whilst testing my app.

```java
service.children().delete(folderId=parent_id, childId=file_id).execute()
service.files().delete(fileId=file_id).execute()
```

Comment: This gives me: `TypeError: createMethod.<locals>.method() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given`

Answer (score 0):

This is a caching issue, the file has actually been removed. If you try to open the file in the Drive UI you should see something along the lines of "Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist."

It will clear itself soon.