# Google Drive API "delete" method bug?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

++ Cross-posted at the Google Drive SDK Google group ++

I used the "delete" method on a test folder created with the SDK (permission: drive.file for all operations).

Tried twice the insert - delete sequence (and thus created 2 folders) with the same unexpected result: both folder are now "untrashable" using the Drive GUI.  The error message is: "2 items were not removed."

I can rename them and access their content, but that's about it.

If I try to move them, I get the "2 items have been moved from xxx to yyy" message, but they do not actually change directory.

Maybe a Googler can help me get rid of these 2 "permanent" folders?

In the mean time, I reverted to the "trash" method, which seems to work fine (but not on these stubborn folders).

Thanks.

An edit:

[Found a 2 line comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909709/documents-deleted-using-google-docs-api-still-visible-in-google-drive#comment15858152_11910048) that seem to confirm this is an oldish bug (August at the very least).  These 2 folders are in my account to stay...